# Sticky Nav issues on shorter pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a sticky nav just using some simple JS. It seems to be working on most pages but on shorter pages it gets confused and start flickering and cant make up its mind. Wondering how to get this fixed.

Here is my js and ccs

```
    // Sticky Header
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log(jQuery(window).height());
    console.log(jQuery(document).height());
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 115 && jQuery(document).height() - (jQuery(window).height() + 345) > 0)
        jQuery('header').addClass('sticky-header');
    else 
        jQuery('header').removeClass('sticky-header');
});

header#header.sticky-header {
position: fixed;
top:0; 
left:0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999!important;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
```

}

Here is a couple links to see it in action.

Works good on long pages. 
https://dev.myavenuea.com/

Does not work on shorter pages.
https://dev.myavenuea.com/product-category/apparel/accessories-apparel/

Comment: The links you have provided are dead (`Error 403 Forbidden`)  and cannot be reached.

Comment: sorry i had IPs block, i have unblocked them now.

Comment: still not working

Comment: sorry guys, should be working now.

Comment: Try removing `- (jQuery(window).height() + 345)` from your code.

Comment: that seems to do the trick. Still had a little weird jump but its a lot better then it was and I can live with it like this. If you put your solution in an answer I will make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you add the jQuery(window).height with 345, I think it actually adds the window height in which is causing the glitches of it. If you can clone the value and then add them together for the if statement, then it shouldn't be as buggy.